# How do I clear this error: Firebase auth State Changes Error

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-authentication

I am trying to implement the backend of an app I'm creating and I want to start with email and password authentication. I am having trouble with the syntax probably. I created another file for the backend for authentication. I created a class and in that class I used a stream to get the authStateChanges but I'm getting an error under the user and uid.
This is a snippet of my code for better understanding of the question:

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';

class AuthService {
  final FirebaseAuth _firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  Stream<String> get authStateChanges =>
      _firebaseAuth.authStateChanges().map(
        
        (User user) => user.uid,
      
      );

  
}
```

Please can I be shown what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I think you forgot the `listen()` part, here is it:

```
FirebaseAuth.instance
  .authStateChanges()
  .listen((User? user) {
    if (user == null) {
      print('User is currently signed out!');
    } else {
      print('User is signed in!');
    }
  });
```